# How to create new Column using withColumn to concentrate two numeric conlumn as String ?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the dataframe as follow

```
val employees = sc.parallelize(Array[(String, Int, BigInt)](
  ("Rafferty", 31, 222222222), ("Jones", 33, 111111111), ("Heisenberg", 33, 222222222), ("Robinson", 34, 111111111), ("Smith", 34, 333333333), ("Williams", 15, 222222222)
)).toDF("LastName", "DepartmentID", "Code")

employees.show()

 +----------+------------+---------+
|  LastName|DepartmentID|     Code|
+----------+------------+---------+
|  Rafferty|          31|222222222|
|     Jones|          33|111111111|
|Heisenberg|          33|222222222|
|  Robinson|          34|111111111|
|     Smith|          34|333333333|
|  Williams|          15|222222222|
+----------+------------+---------+
```

I want to create another column as personal_id as concentrate DepartmentId and Code. Example: Rafferty => 31222222222

So I write code as follow:

```
val anotherdf = employees.withColumn("personal_id", $"DepartmentID".cast("String") + $"Code".cast("String"))


 +----------+------------+---------+------------+
|  LastName|DepartmentID|     Code| personal_id|
+----------+------------+---------+------------+
|  Rafferty|          31|222222222|2.22222253E8|
|     Jones|          33|111111111|1.11111144E8|
|Heisenberg|          33|222222222|2.22222255E8|
|  Robinson|          34|111111111|1.11111145E8|
|     Smith|          34|333333333|3.33333367E8|
|  Williams|          15|222222222|2.22222237E8|
+----------+------------+---------+------------+
```

But I got personal_id at double.

```
anotherdf.printSchema

root
 |-- LastName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DepartmentID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Code: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- personal_id: double (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I should use `concat`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat
val anotherdf2 = employees.withColumn("personal_id", concat($"DepartmentID".cast("String"), $"Code".cast("String")))


 +----------+------------+---------+-----------+
|  LastName|DepartmentID|     Code|personal_id|
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+
|  Rafferty|          31|222222222|31222222222|
|     Jones|          33|111111111|33111111111|
|Heisenberg|          33|222222222|33222222222|
|  Robinson|          34|111111111|34111111111|
|     Smith|          34|333333333|34333333333|
|  Williams|          15|222222222|15222222222|
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+
```